# How to add dictionary in vim for auto completion in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I have searched for this and got answer but there have a problem.
Each time I have to press a short Key.

Is it possible to add a dictionary but not press any short key for auto completion?

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and my vim version is 7.4.52.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are bothered that Vim's insert mode completions need to be triggered by a key [combination]. You would rather have those candidate matches appear automatically, as you type, and have *dictionary completion* as a source.

The [acp.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) (formerly named AutoComplPop) automatically opens the completion popup as you type. With the `g:acp_completeOption` configuration, you can make it use a dictionary source.

Comment: I have downloaded vim-autocomplpop.zip and extract then put vim-autocomplpop(folder) in ~/.vim. Then what can I do? Please, help.

Comment: Remove that `vim-autocomplpop` intermedia folder. The structure needs to be `~/.vim/autoload/acp.vim` and so on. After the plugin is installed, you should immediately notice that the completion menu pops up automatically during typing.

Comment: `set dictionary+=/usr/share/dict/words`

Comment: I have add this line in `~/.vimrc `set dictionary+=/usr/share/dict/words`. Sorry, I don't know what will be done next.

Comment: Does the autocomplpop plugin work by now? Do you see the completion popup open up when typing (long words)?

Comment: To make autocomplpop work, you need the L9 library as well.